# Td widths not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

With only  Bootstrap css the table width works fine, but with my css styles the td width displays very bad.

```
<table>                                                                            
     <tbody>                       
        {#items}
        <tr onclick="selectPickPoint(this);">
            <td width="50" align="center"><input name="pickpointid" type="radio" value="{customer_id}"></td>
            <td width="300">
                <b>{name}</b> <i style="font-size:9px;">#{customer_id}</i>
                <br>
                {address} <br> {postal_code} <a href="{map_link}" target="_blank" style="font-size:10px;">(ver en el mapa</a>)</td>
        </tr>
        {/items}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can check here the rendered example (see chose store table):
https://jsfiddle.net/5ghpqx8L/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the following css in your fiddle:

```
.puntosdeventa input, .puntosdeventa select {
  width: 235px;
}
```

This is causing your problem. If you can replace this css with the following line it will work just fine:

```
.puntosdeventa input, .puntosdeventa select {
  width: auto;
}
```

I would recommend using a different css declaration for the inputs and selects. Most probably you want to have a wider select element than the input.

Comment: Haha yeah :P I was actually debating with my self if this should be just a comment but you never know about the skill level of the asker etc. This will do this time :)

Comment: I was lost when I see the whole code in the fiddle (Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example has no sense for OP, LOL), so I close inmediately the browser tab. But when I close the tab I see your answer, and I test it and it works. So this is the correct answer. :)

Comment: Okay, that's nice! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also change these lines to fix it:

Old:

```
.puntosdeventa input, .puntosdeventa select {
   width: 235px;
 }
```

New:

```
.puntosdeventa input[type='text'], .puntosdeventa select {
    width:235px;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ghpqx8L/5/

Answer (score 1):

You've set the width of the all inputs (including radio buttons) to be 235px, which is forcing the first column to expand.

Try adding a new style rule, something like:

```
.puntosdeventa input[type='radio'] { width:auto; }
```